# Relationship between $H^1(X, \mathbb{T})$ and complex line bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and consider the sheaf cohomology group $H^1(X, \mathbb{T})$. From a class in $H^1(X, \mathbb{T})$, I can get a principal $\mathbb{T}$-bundle over $X$ and from this, an associated complex line bundle. What is the relationship between classes in  $H^1(X, \mathbb{T})$ and complex line bundles? Does one class give me the same line bundle up to isomorphism?

Comment: What's $\mathbb{T}$?

Comment: @Donu Arapura: presumably $U(1)$?

Comment: I assume $\mathbb T =U(1)$ the circle group. From line bundles to cohomology it's: take a trivializing cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ and transition functions $\{g_{\alpha\beta}\}$; the latter represent a Cech cohomology class. From principal bundles to line bundles it's associated bundle construction $L=P\times^\mathbb{T}\mathbb{C}$. From line bundles to principal bundles it's taking the (unitary) frame bundle $L\mapsto \mathrm{Fr}^{U(1)}(L)$. From cohomology to line bundles it's: take a Cech cocycle $(\{U_\alpha\},\{g_{\alpha \beta}\}$ representative and use it as transition functions.

Comment: Yes, by $\mathbb{T}$ I mean $U(1)$.

Comment: Are you seeing $\mathbb{T}$ with the discrete topology or are you imagining as some kind of sheaf of topological groups?

Comment: And, as Denis Nardin suggests, it should probably be $H^1(X,\mathcal{C}_{X,\mathbb{T}})$ where $\mathcal{C}_{X,\mathbb{T}}$ is the sheaf of $\mathbb{T}$-valued continuous functions on $X$, instead of $H^1(X,\mathbb{T})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least if $X$ has the homotopy type of a CW complex, there is a natural isomorphism between $H^1(X; \mathbb T)$ and the group of isomorphism classes of line bundles on $X$ under tensor product.

The usual way this is phrased is that the first Chern class defines an isomorphism from the group of line bundles to $H^2(X;\mathbb Z)$. For example, and for a proof, see [Hatcher, "Vector bundles and $K$-theory," Prop. 3.10](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) (p. 86).

Now consider the short exact sequence of sheaves

$$0\to \mathbb Z\to\mathbb R\to\mathbb R/\mathbb Z\to 0,$$

where $\mathbb R$ carries the continuous topology (i.e., this is the sheaf of continuous real-valued functions on $X$). We have $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z\cong\mathbb T$. There is an induced long exact sequence in cohomology, but as Donu Arapura notes in [an answer to a different MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/29383/97265), $H^k(X;\mathbb R)$ vanishes for $k > 0$. Therefore the long exact sequence simplifies to

$$ 0 \to H^1(X; \mathbb T)\longrightarrow H^2(X; \mathbb Z)\to 0, $$

so $H^1(X;\mathbb T)$ is isomorphic to the group of line bundles. It takes a little more work to see that the isomorphism is the same as the map you described (associated line bundle to a principal $\mathbb T$-bundle), but that is also true.

---

Not all compact metric spaces have the homotopy type of CW complexes, as noted by [Milnor](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1959-090-02/S0002-9947-1959-0100267-4/S0002-9947-1959-0100267-4.pdf) (end of section 1). I unfortunately don't know what the answer to your question is for those spaces.